# IE 9 Save Target As changing file extension from ASF to ASX

Tags: internet-explorer-9, file-extension

I have a simple ASPX webpage on a .NET 4.0 website that has an embeded Windows Media player object and links to download that video in multiple formats (mp4, mp3, high quality asf, low quality asf).

In Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421) both 32 and 64 bit, if I right either of the ASF links and click "Save Target As", a windows Save As dialog box opens (as expected) with the correct file name but with an ASX extension instead of ASF. This happens on multiple machines.

In Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera saving from the same links show the file with the correct ASF extension. I've checked IIS and it has the correct MIME type for ASF. I've also checked my computer and it ASF file extension is registered and pointing to Windows Media Player.

Any ideas what I can do to get IE 9 to save it as an ASF?